# SharePoint Provider Hosted App - SecurityTokenException: Invalid issuer or signature

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, acs, sts-securitytokenservice

I developed a SharePoint Provided Hosted App which is deployed to an Office 365 SharePoint site for testing purposes. Everything works as expected until recently I want it to test with another O365 account. Both of the accounts have exactly the same rights. The only difference is that the second one is created months later.

As you may already guessed, the second user cannot use the app. I tried using different browsers, and even different computers. I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong on the client-side because it works for one user. (I cleared browser cache and Temporary Interet Files for each cases.)

**Problem:**

- One user can just click the app and run it.
- The other user can also click the app link on SharePoint site, but
  then receives an empty page.

So, I checked my logs. It seems after "appredirect" (which happens to be run when you click on your app in SharePoint), the comminication between sharepoint server and my web application starts and immediately stops because of the following exception :

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException: Invalid issuer or signature.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Tokens.JsonWebSecurityTokenHandler.VerifySignature(String signingInput, String signature, String algorithm, SecurityToken signingToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Tokens.JsonWebSecurityTokenHandler.ReadTokenCore(String token, Boolean isActorToken)
```

I tried restarting IIS and deleting ASP.NET Temporary Files.

Does anyone any ideas or any explanation what might go wrong here?

As I mentioned several times, it only happens for this one specific user. 
I will update my post after I create a new account and try with it as the third option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We slept on it and the next day the issue was resolved. 
We still don't know what the problem was and probably never know what really happened.

[Here is another approach from MSDN](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2015/03/11/provider-hosted-app-fails-on-spo.aspx) to overcome this issue unlike our "sleep over" solution but I think it will give you the idea.